# Get name and image from a list of sub categories in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to get all subcategories of a Magento category and display their name and image.

So far I have:

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(28);

foreach ($children as $category) {
    echo "name: " . $category->getName() . "<br>"; 
    echo "image: " . $category->getImageUrl() . "<br>"; 
}
```

`$category->getName()` works, but `$category->getImageUrl()` doesn't seem to.

I am following the [Magento docs](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/) reference of the catalog / category model (see Mage:Catalog along the top then Mage_Catalog_Model_Category at the side).

It clearly states that `string getImageUrl ()` is an available method of the class, however I obviously can't call it.

I'd like to know why in the above this method isn't available, and also more generally, why a lot of methods don't seem to be available from a class so I can understand how to solve these recurring problems in the future.

So, my question is, what does the above need to make the `getImageUrl` method available, and, generally how can I identify what needs adding to make other methods that are in the docs but unavailable by 'default' in the Magento framework?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:-

```
<?php
    //gets all sub categories of parent category
    $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(6)->getChildren();
    $catIds = explode(',',$cats);

    $categories = array();
    foreach($catIds as $catId) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId); 
        $categories[$category->getName()] = array(
            'url' => $category->getUrl(),
            'img' => $category->getImageUrl()
        );
    }

    ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($categories as $name => $data): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                    <img class="cat-image" src="<?php echo $data['img']; ?>" />
                </a>
            </li>   
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that works... Do you know if there's a method where you don't have to manually build the array from the IDs string? I'm sure Magento has a method to get all that data in one call?... This is very helpful too, cheers.